# string concatenation and reference equality

Tags: c#, .net, memory

In C# strings are immutable and managed. In theory that would mean the concatenation of any strings `A` and `B` would cause the allocation of a new buffer however this is all pretty obfuscated. When you concatenate with the identity (the empty string) the reference maintains intact. Is this a compile time optimization or is the overloaded assignment operator making the decision to not realloc at runtime? Furthermore, how does the runtime/compiler handle `s2`'s value/allocation when I modify the value of `s1`? My program would indicate that the memory at the original address of `s1` remains intact (and `s2` continues pointing there) while a relloc occurs for the new value and then `s1` is pointed there, is this an accurate description of what happens under the covers?

Example program;

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s1 = "Some random text I chose";
        string s2 = s1;
        string s3 = s2;

        Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2)); // true

        s1 = s1 + "";

        Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2)); // true
        Console.WriteLine(s2);

        s1 = s1 + " something else";

        Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2)); // false cause s1 got realloc'd
        Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(s2, s3));
        Console.WriteLine(s2);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: Don't forget that there's string interning too to throw into the mix :-)

Comment: What exactly is your question? These are just some observations about one simple optimization. For the s1/s2 confusion, find a tutorial about reference types. One with pictures. __`s1` is not a `string`__

Comment: Add this: `Object.ReferenceEquals("Hi Evan", "Hi Evan");` and see what the result is.

Comment: @HenkHolterman the main question is what is the optimization that causes that behavior? Is it happening at runtime or compile time?

Comment: @Cameron well yeah I think the `s2` to `s3` compare is demonstrating that all the string is interned and `s1` used to point there but no longer does.

Comment: Why would that matter? And you have already proven your starting point "the concatenation of any ... cause the allocation..." to be wrong. There is no mystery here.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think there's a hell of a lot of mystery surrounding strings. They behave differently than every other reference type in the .NET framework. When and where the optimization is happening could have significant performance implications when it's a real program processing 'big data' and not the contrived example above. My question was motivated by "should I thumbs this PR that does identity concatenation all over the place for no reason?". Even if I know the answer that doesn't mean it's not worth asking. It's not a duplicate, most people seem to *not know* what's happening.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal They don't behave any differently than *any* reference type in the .NET framework.  If you're concerned about whether a particularly operation is too slow or not then *profile the code*.  If you see that a lot more work is being done concatting strings than you think there should be, *then* would be the time to investigate.

Comment: You confuse things by calling the empty string 'identity'. Nobody else does that. There are no promises that `ref(x+"") == ref(x)`, that's just opportunism.

Comment: @HenkHolterman And of course if `x` is `null` it would violate the documented semantics of the `+` operator for that expression to be true, so it *must* be false at least some of the time.

Comment: @HenkHolterman that's actually the widely used terminology in academia... I don't see what your objection is to my wanting to understand how that 'opportunity' or lack of opportunity is decided. You think there's no value in knowing what the internals of `Concat` look like or what pre-compile steps change that code? It's not the answer but the explanation that's valuable. Why do people on SO have such a hard time understanding that?

Comment: I would shoot down any code that relies on such coincidental features... For either semantics or performance. The only issue here is if any of this behavior is nailed down in a spec. Who does which optimization when is of no practical use.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I'm not relying on it or using it at all, just wanted to better understand what's happening. The information you're talking about is what I was looking for and is in the answers. Excuse my phrasing of the question but of course I wasn't looking for someone to say "yes, yes", I wanted technical explanation of how it's happening.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When you concatenate with the identity (the empty string) the reference maintains intact. Is this a compile time optimization or is the overloaded assignment operator making the decision to not realloc at runtime?

It is both a compile time optimization and also an optimization performed in the implementation of the overloaded *concatenation* operator.  If you concat two compile time literals, or concat a string known to be null or empty at compile time, the concatenation is done at compile time, and then potentially interned, and will therefore be reference equal to any other compile time literal string that has the same value.

Additionally, `String.Concat` is implemented such that if you concat a string with either `null` or an empty string, it just returns the other string (unless the other string was `null`, in which case it returns an empty string).  The test you already have demonstrates this, as you're concatting a non-compile time literal string with an empty string and it's staying reference equal.

Of course if you don't believe your own test, you can [look at the source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,55b2f6374a7cf7c1) to see that if one of the arguments is null then it simply returns the other.

```
if (IsNullOrEmpty(str0)) {
    if (IsNullOrEmpty(str1)) {
        return String.Empty;
    }
    return str1;
}

if (IsNullOrEmpty(str1)) {
    return str0;
}
```

Comment: Just to add, this line `s1 = s1 + "";` under ILSpy looks like `s1 = (s1 ?? "");`

Comment: Tha's not correct. There is no overloaded assignment operator that makes such a decision, as the assignment operator can't be overloaded.

Comment: @Guffa It is correct, as it has nothing to do with the assignment operator, but rather the `+` operator.  It's also an optimization by the compiler to *avoid calling the `+` operator* rather than by the implementation of the operator itself.

Comment: @Servy: You are contradicting yourself. In the answer you are saying that what the OP is saying about the overloaded assignment operator is correct, now you are saying that it has nothing to do wih the assignment operator.

Comment: @Guffa Sorry, I misread the OP's statement and assumed he was referring to the `+` operator, not the assignment operator.  I've edited to adjust for that.

Answer (score 4):

> When you concatenate with the identity (the empty string) the reference maintains intact. Is this a compile time optimization or is the overloaded assignment operator making the decision to not realloc at runtime?

This is a run-time optimization. Here is how it is implemented in Mono:

```
public static String Concat(String str0, String str1) {
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result() != null);
    Contract.Ensures(Contract.Result().Length ==
        (str0 == null ? 0 : str0.Length) + 
        (str1 == null ? 0 : str1.Length));
    Contract.EndContractBlock(); 

    // ========= OPTIMIZATION BEGINS ===============
    if (IsNullOrEmpty(str0)) {
        if (IsNullOrEmpty(str1)) { 
            return String.Empty;
        }
        return str1;
    } 

    if (IsNullOrEmpty(str1)) { 
        return str0; 
    }
    // ========== OPTIMIZATION ENDS =============

    int str0Length = str0.Length;

    String result = FastAllocateString(str0Length + str1.Length);

    FillStringChecked(result, 0,        str0);
    FillStringChecked(result, str0Length, str1); 

    return result;
}
```

The compiler may produce additional optimizations of its own - for example, concatenating two string literals produces a new literal value at compile time, without calling `string.Concat`. This is not different from C#'s handling of other expressions that include compile-time constants of other data types, though.

> Furthermore, how does the runtime/compiler handle `s2`'s value/allocation when I modify the value of `s1`?

`s1` and `s2` are independent references to the same `string` object, which is immutable. Reassigning another object to one of them does not change the other reference.

Answer (score 1):

It is a decision by the String.Concat function not to concat the string. It checks whether s1 is null and assigns "" to s1 if yes.

---

```
s1 = s1 + "";
```

gets optimized by the comiler.

```
s1 = s1 ?? "";
```

---

If you want to learn more check out [this link](http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/17/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-one/)

Answer (score 1):

String concatenation is specified to return a string whose sequence of characters is the concatenation of the sequences encapsulated by the string representations of the things being concatenated.  In cases where no existing string contains the proper sequence of characters, the concatenation code will need to create a new one; further, even in cases where an existing string might contain the proper sequence of characters, it will usually be faster for the computer to create a new string than try to find the existing one.  I believe, however, that concatenation is allowed to return an existing string in any case where it can quickly find one that contains the proper characters, and in the case of concatenating a zero-length string to a non-zero-length string, finding a string which contains the proper characters is easy.

Because of behavioral details like the above, in most cases the only legitimate application of `ReferenceEquals` with strings is in situations where a `true` result is interpreted to say "the strings definitely contain the same characters" and a "false" result to say "the strings *might* not contain the same characters".  It should not be interpreted as saying anything about where the strings came, how they were created, or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

> When you concatenate with the identity (the empty string) the
>   reference maintains intact. Is this a compile time optimization or is
>   the overloaded assignment operator making the decision to not realloc
>   at runtime?

Neither. It's the `Concat` method that does that decision. The code is actually compiled into:

```
s1 = String.Concat(s1, "");
```

The `Concat` method contains this code, that makes it return the first parameter if the second is empty:

```
if (IsNullOrEmpty(str1)) {
  return str0;
}
```

Ref: [Microsoft reference source: String.Concat(string, string)](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,55b2f6374a7cf7c1)

> My program would indicate that the memory at the original address of
>   s1 remains intact (and s2 continues pointing there) while a relloc
>   occurs for the new value and then s1 is pointed there

That is correct.

Comment: Why the downvote? If you don't explain what it is that you think is wrong, it can't improve the answer.